# Why isn't this div node the child to the container?

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

Developing an Etch-A-Sketch - I created a 16*16 grid using a 2 for loops - one nested in the other.

```
        const div =  document.createElement('div');
        div.style.cssText = 'flex: 1';
        container.appendChild(div);
        // div.addEventListener('mouseover', changeBackground);
        for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++){
            const div2 = document.createElement('div');
            div2.classList.add('square');
            div.style.display = 'flex';
            div.appendChild(div2);
```

In this for loop I create a div and assign it to `const div` then that gets appended as a CHILD node to the container - `const container = document.querySelector('.container');`. In the inner for loop `const div2 = document.createElement('div');` is assigned as a child to `const div` in the outer loop because div2 are the squares on the grid. So the DOM tree looks like this:

[image: DOM tree for EtchASketch project] -

At the moment what I want to do is set up an event listener which will fire when the user clicks on a button to give them the option to set a grid of their choice - (i.e. prompt which asks them to enter a number between 2 and 64, and then in similar fashion I want to iterate loop variables i and j - as many times as the user's input suggested and then generate a input * input grid. However, the first thing I need to do is clear the grid of its existing 16 * 16 squares - so that's where I decided to make use of the `removeChild()` method and remove `const div` from `container` and remove `const div2` from `const div`. I am able to successfully call and remove `div.removeChild(div2);`. However I run into an error - **Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node** , when I run `container.removeChild(div);`. I have already looked up the error somewhat and have seen that you can't remove descendants using the `removeChild()` method however from the DOM tree above I'm pretty much sure that `div` is a child to the `container` element. So my question is: what is the cause of this error and how can I go about fixing it? Does it have something to do with `container` having a parent of its own - `containerBorder`?

```
              //sets grid depending on what number the user specifies.
                container.removeChild(div);
                // let userPrompt = prompt('Generate a grid: Enter a number between 2 and 100: ');
                // let input = Number.parseInt(userPrompt, 10);
                // container.removeChild(div);
                // div.removeChild(div2);
                // console.log(typeof input);
                // for(let i = 0; i < 16; i++){
                //     let div = document.createElement('div');
                //     div.style.cssText = 'border: 1px solid black; flex: 1';
                //     container.appendChild(div);

                //     for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++){
                //         let div2 = document.createElement('div');
                //         div2.classList.add('square');
                //         div2.style.display = 'flex';
                //         div.appendChild(div2);
                //     }
                // }

            });
```

The full code is here - https://codepen.io/safdari/pen/oNXJBGY

Answer (score 0):

`container.innerHTML = ''` will clear the container and allow me to re-render it